# Platform Connect / External Data Source from Siebel

Tags: custom-object, lightning-connect, odata

I have to connect with in-premises Siebel system to a get the data for a Lookup in SFDC. Can we connect with Siebel with External Data source method ?

I can see Siebel EBC here in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000204599&language=en_US) but don't know how to integrate with it and get the data in external object. Thanks

Comment: can u provide the link which you are referring to ..

Comment: Sure Vamsi ....   https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000204599&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Platform Connect is now branded as Lightning Connect.  You can use it with "anything," so long as it is exposed in a manner that Salesforce understands.  Currently, Salesforce only supports OData v2.  If you have a way to expose your Siebel data in the OData version 2 format, you can use Lightning Connect with it. Some third party vendors like Informatica and Mulesoft offer solutions for that; I don't know that Siebel has any OData solutions that would work "out of the box."

Answer (score 1):

I am with Progress Software. We are one of the 3rd-party vendors who offer Lightning Connect "gateways". A customer of ours is in production with 5,500 Salesforce users accessing on-premise Siebel data on an Oracle database using Lightning Connect through DataDirect Cloud. (We handle getting through the firewall.) No changes to the Siebel environment. You can trial our solution for free for 30 days. Fully functional.