# OData for Siebel/Oracle to connect with Salesforce using Lightning Connect

Tags: lightning-connect, odata

We want to expose Siebel data in Salesforce using Lightning Connect.As of now Lightning Connect supports OData v2.0 format.Can anyone let me know how to change Siebel data into OData v2 format.Underlying database for Siebel is Salesforce.Do I need to change Oracle's data into OData format?If so,please give some insight into it

Comment: Hi Suneel,   I had put the same question few days ago.    http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71343/platform-connect-external-data-source-from-siebel....   It may help

Comment: Hi amidstCloud,thanks for the link...Did you make any progress in OData direction?

Comment: I have done some research and found that we can either write our own OAuth producer to expose Oracle's data in OData v2 format(which involves lot of effort and time) or can use products like CDATA's Cloud Drivers or Progress Data Direct Cloud to expose relational data in OData v2 format from link- "http://www.odata.org/ecosystem/". Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with Progress, the folks behind DataDirect Cloud that you mentioned. One of our earliest successes with Lightning Connect has been integrating Siebel data residing on Oracle. The customer has 5,500 users live using this today. Hope to have a public success story soon. You can sign up for a fully-functional free 30-day eval and test out connecting to your Siebel environment. We even take care of getting through the firewall.

No changes are required at the database level - the Oracle system simply sees SQL queries. DataDirect Cloud reformats the data dynamically into OData v2 when accessed from Salesforce and Lightning Connect.

Comment: Progress is a paid tool and we are looking for any free solution to achieve the same.I created OAuth producer by following the link-http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/02/05/odata-producer-using-apache-olingo-with-mysql-jpa-tomcat-web-server.It is serving well for me as of now